# Why is the BehaviorSubject not async?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created a method to be able to return if the data has already been entered in the store and loaded, but this way it is not `async`.

It only looks `async` if I insert a variable outside, inside the `subscribe`.

What happens is that the value is "`true`" which is the initial value of the Behavior

**SERVICE**

```
export class StoreService {
    constructor(protected readonly userStore: UserStoreService, protected readonly chatStore: ChatStoreService) {}

    create(): void {
        this.userStore.setAll();
        this.chatStore.setAll();
    }

    get loading(): BehaviorSubject<boolean> {
        const isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(true);

        timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
            combineLatest([this.userStore.loading, this.chatStore.loading])
                .pipe(
                    filter(([userLoading, chatLoading]) => !userLoading && !chatLoading),
                    takeWhile(([userLoading, chatLoading]) => !userLoading && !chatLoading)
                )
                .subscribe(() => isLoading.next(false));
        });

        return isLoading;
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public readonly store: StoreService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.create();
    }
}

{{ store.loading | async | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up differently

```
export class StoreService {
   public isLoading$ = new BehaviourSubject(true);

   constructor(protected readonly userStore: UserStoreService, protected readonly chatStore: ChatStoreService) {}

  create(): void {
    this.userStore.setAll();
    this.chatStore.setAll();
    this.load();
  }

  load(): void {
    const isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(true);

    timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
      combineLatest([this.userStore.loading, this.chatStore.loading])
        .pipe(filter(([userLoading, chatLoading]) => !userLoading && !chatLoading),takeWhile(([userLoading, chatLoading]) => !userLoading && !chatLoading))
     .subscribe(() => this.isLoading$.next(false));
    });
  }
}
```

then in your `AppComponent`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private store: StoreService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.create();
  }
}

{{ store.isLoading$ | async | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of `get loading()` is that every time it's called it returns a new stream despite it relies on `this.userStore.loading` and `this.chatStore.loading`.

you need to make it fix, as an option make it a readonly property that does the same:

```js
export class StoreService {
  constructor(protected readonly userStore: UserStoreService, protected readonly chatStore: ChatStoreService) {}

  create(): void {
    this.userStore.setAll();
    this.chatStore.setAll();
  }

  // to add $ to mark it as an observable is a nice style.
  public readonly loading$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest([
    this.userStore.loading,
    this.chatStore.loading,
  ]).pipe(
    // maps to true if anyone is loading.
    map(flags => flags.indexOf(true) !== -1),

    // our start value is true.
    startWith(true),
  );
}
```

and now every time when one of them or both are loading it will return true, otherwise false.

```js
{{ store.loading$ | async | json }}
```